# how to check if you have already subscribed to EWS notifications/PushSubscriptionRequest

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am writing a service to listen to push notifications from EWS. I have a problem that If while running test runs, I restart the service, when I restart the service I send another `PushSubscriptionRequest`.

Has anyone run into a similar problem? any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to pickup where your last subscription left off (*after a host service restart*) - you need a persistence mechanism to track the previous push subscription's [`SubscriptionID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563790%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

According to [TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/da/exchangesvrdevelopment/thread/3baa0e2d-67e7-4eb8-a996-4cf16b33b145) - you cannot query the status of a `PushSubscription`, you can only set a [`StatusFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa564048%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx).

---

> [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566188%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx):
> *A new **SubscriptionId** is created when you resubscribe. Use the watermark of a previous subscription to resubscribe at the point where the previous subscription ended.*

Comment: @Jelmer - removed the link, site seems dead now. thanks!